# How to make this an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to make this an array but where I've put the brackets it just gives an error out.

```
Texture2D* sun = new Texture2D();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
Texture2D* sun = new Texture2D[size];
```

See [operator new[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new%5B%5D/).

Comment: I've done this. Texture2D* sun = new Texture2D()[10]; but now I get the error of no suitable conversion function from "Texture2D" to "Texture2D*" exists

Comment: Try `Texture2D* sun = new Texture2D[10];`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to do something like this:

```
Texture2D** sun = new Texture2D*[size];
```

Comment: I've done this. Texture2D* sun = new Texture2D()[10]; but now I get the error of no suitable conversion function from "Texture2D" to "Texture2D*" exists

Comment: @RussNicholls You must use my answer or al-Acme answer. not `Texture2D()[10];`